# Rebus network transport: how to guide

Tags: rebus

Is there a sample project/documentation that shows how to set up two Rebus components on different machines?

In particular over HTTPS

Answer (score 0):

Rebus cannot really use HTTP/HTTPS as a transport. Rebus can only live up to its message delivery guarantees by having a transport layer that supports some kind of (preferably [durable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Durability_(database_systems))) [store and forward](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Store_and_forward).

If you are using Windows to host your things, you can [install MSMQ](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa967729(v=vs.110).aspx) and use that as a transport. With MSMQ as the transport, you can send to a queue on another machine by using the `queuename@machinename` syntax.

At the moment you can also use SQL Server (possibly the free Express edition), RabbitMQ, Azure Service Bus/Storage Queues, or Amazon SQS as transports.

Comment: Thanks bro.  Love your work!  You are my new Dev Hero!